# XSLT convert date format

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, biztalk, xslt-1.0

I'm having an issue where I'm getting an XML file, and from the samples that I get the format of date that I'm getting is `mm/dd/yyyy` and sometimes it is `m/d/yyyy`. My task is to convert this to another XML file where the schema only accepts `yyyy-mm-dd`. I'm limited to using XSLT 1.0/XPATH 1.0. How can I do this?

Comment: So how would you interpret '11/12/2012' ?
You need to clarify your question with rules about which of the two formats applies in which cases.

Comment: With the source schema being 11/12/2012 the target schema would need to have that as 2012-11-12 (interpreted as 2012 November 12).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is a little vague. It needs some sample input and expected output. But any way, here is an answer to best guess at what you want.

Given this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dates>
  <date>11/12/2012</date>
  <date>3/4/2011</date>
</dates>
```

... transformed by this style-sheet ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="dates">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="date">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select=" 
           concat(
           substring-after(substring-after(.,'/'),'/') , '-',
           format-number( number( substring-before(.,'/')), '00') , '-',
           format-number( substring-before(substring-after(.,'/'),'/'), '00') 
           )
          " />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will produce this desired output ...

```
<dates>
 <date>2012-11-12</date>
 <date>2011-03-04</date>
</dates>
```

Please tick the answer if it is correct. I verified this solution on http://www.purplegene.com/static/transform.html

Comment: Dogbane's solution is pretty similiar to mine, but he beat me to the punch. Still, I think my solution is briefer and reads better. McLaren's solution won't work on dates like 1/12/2012 which has string length 9.

Answer (score 1):

My XSLT shown below should work. It does not use hard-coded lengths or indexes, but instead splits the date string on '/' to work out where the day, month and year components are.

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

        <!-- match the date and invoke formatDate to format it -->
    <xsl:template match="date">
        <xsl:element name="date">
            <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
                <xsl:with-param name="dateParam" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="formatDate">
        <xsl:param name="dateParam" />
        <!-- input format mm/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy -->
        <!-- output format yyyy-mm-dd -->


        <!-- parse out the day, month and year -->
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before($dateParam,'/')" />
        <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before(substring-after($dateParam,'/'),'/')" />
        <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-after(substring-after($dateParam,'/'),'/')" />

        <!-- now print them out. Pad with 0 where necessary. -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$year" />
        <xsl:value-of select="'-'" />
        <xsl:if test="string-length($month) = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="'0'" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="$month" />
        <xsl:value-of select="'-'" />
        <xsl:if test="string-length($day) = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="'0'" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="$day" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input:**

```
<input>
    <date>04/30/2012</date>
    <date>4/1/2012</date>
</input>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
    <date>2012-04-30</date>
    <date>2012-04-01</date>
</input>
```

**Demo**: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/kBveVQ

Comment: Please don't use `<xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="xxx"/></xsl:variable>` when you could use `<xsl:variable select="xxx"/>`. It's verbose and inefficient!

Comment: Hello team! 
See below , exposing format-dateTime: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16892467/2816548