# Convert a string to Date format in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, date-format

I have a date(string) value in an XML file in this format:

```
Tue Apr 17 03:12:47 IST 2012
```

I want to use XSL transformation to convert the string/date into this format:

```
4/17/2012 03:12:47 AM
```

How can I do that in my XSL transform?

Comment: Which xslt version (1.0, 2.0) can/would you use?

Comment: I can use both in fact. Would prefer 1.0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using

- XSLT 1.0 version, use **[EXSLT - date:format-date](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/format-date/index.html)** date extension
- XSLT 2.0 version, use **[built-in: Formatting Dates and Times](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date)** date extension

But my suggestion is to

> **Have a standard XSD datetime format on XML, on the code-behind (that is, on rendering time) you can format as you like.**

### Update:

Always XML to process through XSLT, dates should be in standard XSD format. Currently your input is not in standard format so that it throws error.

***Example:***

```
<xsl:variable name="dt" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime('2012-10-21T22:10:15')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($dt, '[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]')"/>
```

***OUTPUT:***

2012/10/21

Comment: I am using the format-dateTime function (2.0) and its giving me this error:

'Invalid dateTime value "Tue Apr 17 03:12:47 IST 2012" (Non-numeric year component)'

Comment: @RohitGupta: Show your xslt

Comment: `<Date><xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(CreatedDate, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')" /></Date>`

Comment: @SivaCharan I got an Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown XPath extension function was called. exaption, may be you know where is the problem

Comment: @ArturKeyan: Its better you can post a new question with detailed error message and your XSLT. So that I can help you.

Comment: I got an Error :Prefix 'xs' is not defined