# Convert dd/mm/yy to dd-MM-YYYY format in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, date-formatting

Thanks in advance for your support.

I have the date formats as `dd/MMM/YY` and need to be converted into the another format `dd-MM-YYYY` using `XSL`.

The problem here is, year is in short format need to be converted into long format. How can the year be determined ?

Here are few examples,

```
dd/MMM/YY - dd-MM-YYYY

01/FEB/91 - 01-02-1991.

13/APR/13 - 13-04-2013.
```

Using string manipulations,`XSL` it can be converted to long format but actual year cannot be determined.

For example

`01/FEB/91` can be converted to `01-02-1991` or `01-02-2091` using string functions.

So, how to get the actual date using `XSL 1.0 or XSL 2.0` ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892344/convert-a-string-to-date-format-in-xslt

Comment: I have edited my question just now. Please review.

Comment: how to get the "actual date" ? just concat "20" before year as you can't go back in time...

Comment: All the input data what I have is related to date of birth.

Comment: Sorry my mistake ('actual' != 'actuel' = 'current' in french)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about what you're asking. XSLT has no way of knowing whether 01/FEB/91 means 01-02-1991 or 01-02-2091 or 01-02-1891. You need to decide where the cutoff year is.

You could make the cutoff 2013 and do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="longYear"
              select="$shortYear + 2000 - (100 * ($shortYear > 13))" />
```

This will result in 20XX for years less than or equal to 13, and 19XX for years greater than 13.

In its own template:

```
<xsl:template name="LongYear">
  <xsl:param name="shortYear" select="." />
  <xsl:param name="cutoff" select="13" />

  <xsl:value-of select="$shortYear + 2000 - (100 * ($shortYear > $cutoff))" />
</xsl:template>
```

Which you can invoke with:

```
<xsl:call-template name="LongYear">
  <xsl:with-param name="shortYear" select="substring(Date, 8, 2)" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: What I was looking, is there any in built function/pattern to do the operation what you have suggested.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be, but it should be easy enough to put this into its own template and make it reusable. In XSLT 2.0 you could also define a function that does this so that you can use it inline.

Comment: To be more generic, I have changed a bit of your code,   <xsl:template name="LongYear">
  <xsl:param name="shortYear" select="." />

  <xsl:value-of select="$shortYear + 2000 - (100 * ($shortYear > (The last two digits of current year)))" />
</xsl:template>

Answer (score 0):

You can use customized java function in xslt as this date conversion is possible in Java for the same.

Comment: No, you can't "*use customized java function in xslt*". You can use Java functions only in those XSLT processors that will let you use them as part of their extensions mechanism.