# XSLT ISO 8601 Time format

Tags: xml, xslt, time

I have an XML where I get this attribute:

```
Trans_dtmBookingStamp="Fri, 15 Nov, 2013 @ 3:20pm"
```

I want to convert the time stamp, with XSLT, to an ISO8601 Format like this:

```
2013-11-13T15:20:00+02:00
```

Comment: What version of XSLT? Can you post an example of what you've tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse string to date in xslt 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851726/how-to-parse-string-to-date-in-xslt-2-0)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892344/convert-a-string-to-date-format-in-xslt

Answer (score -2):

See if this can get you started:

```
<xsl:template name="convertDate">
    <xsl:param name="datestring" />

    <xsl:param name="d" select="substring-before(substring-after($datestring, ' '), ' ')"/>
    <xsl:param name="mmm" select="substring(substring-after(substring-after($datestring, ' '),' '), 1, 3)"/>
    <xsl:param name="m" select="string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', $mmm)) div 3 + 1"/>
    <xsl:param name="y" select="substring(substring-after($datestring, $mmm), 3 , 4)"/>
    <xsl:param name="ymmdd" select="10000*$y+100*$m+$d"/>
    <xsl:param name="mm" select="substring($ymmdd, 5, 2)"/>
    <xsl:param name="dd" select="substring($ymmdd, 7, 2)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat ($y, '-', $mm, '-', $dd, 'T')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Calling this template with a *datestring* parameter of "Fri, 15 Nov, 2013 @ 3:20pm" will return a value of "2013-11-15T". The time portion is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Seriously disturbed people vote me down - but this is good code nevertheless.